# Botones bootstrap diagonal sin rotar texto

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo que hacer que estos botones de bootstrap estén en diagonal, el problema es que cuando fuerzo la diagonal en los botones el texto también se coloca en diagonal haciendo un efecto cursiva. Me gustaría conservar el texto de forma normal pero no se como hacerlo, he pensado en alguna propiedad que afecte solo al texto? pero no logro hacerlo Gracias.

```html
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-dark" style="transform: skewX( -22deg );" type="button">More... </button>  <button class="btn btn-info" style="transform: skewX( -22deg ); background-color: #007ac3; border-color: #007ac3;" type="button">More...</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes añadir una etiqueta `span` al texto del botón para posteriormente volver a restar los grados solamente al texto:

```css
button {
transform: skew(-22deg);
}

span {
display: block;
transform: skew(22deg);
}
```

```html
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><span>More...</span> </button>

</body>
```

Comment: Vaya, lo habia probado con span pero no me habia funcionado, claro, no era display: block como es el div por defecto, ahora lo veo.

Comment: @masterguru ¡Ups! no había visto tu respuesta cuando he empezado a editar la mía. Al parecer la función ``skew`` solamente funciona si el display del elemento está definido previamente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! justo habia probado el span con anterioridad pero no funcionaba jajaja me faltaba también el display block gracias!! me salvas la vida

Comment: @Hechi da igual, parece que el OP prefiere el span y así lo habia probado y le has dado la solución, asi que todos contentos :-)

Answer (score 3):

Una posible solución es encerrar ese texto en un elemento `<div>` y aplicarle el atributo **transform** con el *valor invertido* del mismo atributo que su contenedor, es decir, cambiar esto:

```
More...
```

por esto:

```html
<div style="transform: skewX( 22deg );">More...</div>
```

Aquí dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```html
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-dark" style="transform: skewX( -22deg );" type="button">
    <div style="transform: skewX( 22deg );">More...</div>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" style="transform: skewX( -22deg ); background-color: #007ac3; border-color: #007ac3;" type="button">
    <div style="transform: skewX( 22deg );">More...</div>
</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Millones de Gracias!! era una respuesta super util pero estoy editando un wordpress y por alguna razón me quitaba todo y no me servia.En otro contexto si serviría seguramente. Gracias!!

Comment: De nada :-)  Wordpress tendra alguna hoja de estilos que estará afectando a los <div> de forma global (o justo donde lo estes poniendo ahora) y por eso te da problemas con esta solución.